# Tokenizing until next occurrence of data

Tags: xml, xslt, xslt-1.0, xslt-2.0, xslt-grouping

I have a string like this:

AA 12345678910

BB TESTTESTTEST

BB TESTTESTTEST

BB TESTTESTTEST

CC TEST

AA 0897654321

BB TESTTESTTEST

CC TEST

How would i group by data AA? This is just string by the way.
I can do this by positioning but data BB's are multi occurring.

Is it possible to tokenize a chunk of string. In a sentence: "Group by AA until another AA shows up"

Comment: So what would be the result of the grouping?

Comment: Like this:

<Group1>
     <AA/>
     <BB/>
     <BB/>
     <BB/>
     <CC/>
</Group1>
<Group2>
     <AA/>
     <BB/>
     <CC/>
</Group2>

Comment: But the input is divided into separated lines and the `AA` will be at the start of a line?

Comment: @MartinHonnen yup

Answer (score 1):

Assuming this input:

```
<input>
AA 12345678910
BB TESTTESTTEST
BB TESTTESTTEST
BB TESTTESTTEST
CC TEST
AA 0897654321
BB TESTTESTTEST
CC TEST
</input>
```

and this XSLT

```
<xsl:for-each select="tokenize(input, '^AA ', 'm')">
  <xsl:if test="normalize-space()">
    <block>AA <xsl:value-of select="." /></block>
  </xsl:if>
</xsl:for-each>
```

we get two blocks:

```
<block>AA 12345678910
BB TESTTESTTEST
BB TESTTESTTEST
BB TESTTESTTEST
CC TEST
</block><block>AA 0897654321
BB TESTTESTTEST
CC TEST
</block>
```

`tokenize()` splits the input string at a delimiter, but it removes the delimiter in the process. That's why we need to add the `'AA '` back manually in the output.

Comment: would the code be any different if the input was: AA12345678910? and what is the 'm' for?

Comment: When you give it a moment of thought, you will see what to change in the regex for that case. The `m` is the multi-line switch. It changes the meaning of `^` (and `$`) from "start (end) of string" to "start (end) of line". This way, only `AA` that are at the start of a line are considered, not when they occur randomly anywhere else.  You can use https://regex101.com/ to play around with the data as it actually is in your input. (For your next question: always paste your input XML as it actually is, vague descriptions and arbitrary changes always lead to answers that don't fit your problem.)

Answer (score 0):

In XSLT 3 (supported since 2017 and by Saxon 9.8 and later, Saxon-JS 2, Altova XML 2017 R3 and later) you can use `for-each-group group-starting-with` on a sequence of strings:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    exclude-result-prefixes="#all"
    version="3.0">

  <xsl:output indent="yes"/>

  <xsl:template match="data">
    <xsl:copy>
      <xsl:for-each-group select="tokenize(., '\n')[normalize-space()]" group-starting-with=".[starts-with(., 'AA')]">
        <group pos="{position()}">
          <xsl:apply-templates select="current-group()"/>
        </group>
      </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
  </xsl:template>
  
  <xsl:template match=".[. instance of xs:string]">
    <xsl:element name="{substring(., 1, 2)}"/>
  </xsl:template>
  
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

https://xsltfiddle.liberty-development.net/6qaHaS5

One way in XSLT 2, to use `for-each-group` similar to the above, would be to first transform the text lines into XML elements.